# How to move in AND OUT of Native Module in React Native?

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, react-native

My question has to do with native modules in React and how to switch between Js views and a Swift written native modules. The code I have is pretty boilerplate from various examples.

The goToNativeView function below swaps out the rootViewController to enter the Swift code (through the Main storyboard file). How would I instrument a function call from Swift to return back to my Javascript application?

AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
#ifdef FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED
  InitializeFlipper(application);
#endif

  RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self launchOptions:launchOptions];
  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge
                                                   moduleName:@"RNImageCollectorV2"
                                            initialProperties:nil];

  if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
      rootView.backgroundColor = [UIColor systemBackgroundColor];
  } else {
      rootView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
  }

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
}

// this method will be called from the RCTBridge
- (void) goToNativeView {
    NSLog(@"RN binding - Native View - CameraViewController.swift - Load From main storyboard");
    UIViewController *vc = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil].instantiateInitialViewController;
    self.window.rootViewController = vc;
}
```

In my React Component, I have a simple function that enables the native module. I'm assuming I need a callback or listener for the exit call

App.tsx

```
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  _changeView = () => {
    // this.done = true;
    // this.render();
    NativeModules.ChangeViewBridge.changeToNativeView();
  };

  render() {
    return (
       <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this._changeView()}>
                <Text color="#336699">Press to Change to Native View</Text>
              </TouchableHighlight>
  )}
```